# Open source seismic refraction processing

Tags: geology, geophysics, seismic, software

**What I am in search of is an open source tool to pick first arrivals, plot travel-time curves, and perform simple velocity modeling.**

I am experimenting with seismic refraction to identify shallow subsurface interfaces. This includes the water table in a sand channel and the sand/bedrock contact.

I have a 24 channel Seistronix RAS-24 for field acquisition. This includes a field computer with software to set geometry, run the survey, and record data to various .seg formats.

What I do not have is a reliable program to process and model my data. Thus far I have been evaluating seismograms in the field and calculating depths by hand with the text book equations.

I am open to any freely available software solution that would allow me to interpret and visualize my field data. This includes python or matlab based packages.

**Are there any open source and community supported seismic refraction processing tools available?**

Comment: I think both Madagascar and Seismic UNIX should be able to do it. The packages are mostly aimed for reflection survey data but for your use it should work. Plotting is not the strongest side of Madagascar, but there are a few standalone segy viewers that are nicer to work with (but sometimes difficult to install).

Answer (score 1):

There are several references to refraction tools in the Wikipedia page for free geophysics software:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_geophysics_software

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange!  While linking to content is helpful, we prefer our answers to contain the information relevant to answering the question.  This is to make sure the content of an answer is always available and not dependent on an outside resource.  You are encouraged to edit your answer to include the content you link to and you are fine with copy and pasting as long as you properly attribute the author and the source as Wikipedia.